# Sympy - reducing the order of cos()**n

Tags: python, sympy, trigonometry

**UPDATE 08/20/2023**

I by chance sumbled on the fact that `TR8` by "expanding products of cos in to sums" actually does a very similar thing to the "complex" expressions I want to develop:

[image]

So `TR8` seems to recognize a product for `cos(x)**n` and it therefore unfolds it into sums of `cos` of sum/difference angles. However, on its own it leaves the squared expressions untouched. If I `expand` the intermediate result and re-apply `TR8`, I get where I want to be.

Since my expressions are a little more involved, I end up nesting `TR8(expand(` expressions until I get my desired result, so it is worth looking into the many hints contained in the answers to this question.

---

I am looking for a way to expand powers of sums of cosine functions into sums of cosines of sums/differences of multiple angles. In the simplest form, starting from a square of a sum, one would get a sum of cosines of double angles plus (this is another simplification step) the expansion of a product of two cosines into the sum of cosines of sum and difference angles:

[image]

`sympy` has a set of functions to apply simplifications/transformations to trigonometric expressions, as detailed [here](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/simplify/fu.htm).

In particular, `TR7` is interesting in my case in that it "reduce cos power (increase angle)", as the description says.

This appears to work - however - for `cos()**2` only:

[image]

[image]

... And so on for other higher powers of  `cos`.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/simplify/fu.py), it appears clear why this is the case:

[image]

So it looks like the description in the reference I reported above, is a little misleading.

But now my question is: what is the right way to split something like `cos(x)**(2*n)` into a product of `n` `cos(x)**2` terms?

I started to look into the [expression tree](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/manipulation.html) topic, thinking maybe I will have to parse the expression and break it into `cos(x)**2` atoms and separately apply the `TR7` simplification to each of them, then apply some form of expansion and successively probably `TR8` to complete the last step of multiplication of `cos(n*x)*cos(x)`, or something similar.

I would like to hear if you have any suggestion on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use pattern matching to extract all powers of cosine. Then, rewrite the exponent and apply the `TR7` rule, something like this:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.simplify.fu import TR7
var("x")

expr = cos(x)**(S(5) / 2) + sin(x)**2 + 1
items = expr.find(lambda t: t.is_Pow and isinstance(t.base, cos))
new_expr = expr
for i in items:
    b, e = i.args
    term = Pow(b**2, e / 2, evaluate=False)
    new_expr = expr.subs(i, TR7(term))
new_expr
# out: (cos(2*x)/2 + 1/2)**(5/4) + sin(x)**2 + 1
```

For `TR7` to work as expected, we must set `evaluate=False` when rewriting the power term.

I think one thing should be emphasized: the equivalence you want to apply is not always satisfied. For example, you can try with `expr = cos(x)**3`. The result is different than the original expression (compare them with a plot).

Comment: I cannot fully understand what you mean with "the equivalence you want to apply is not always satisfied", can you please expand on that?
If you mean that you can't write cos(x)**3 as cos(x)**(2*n) it is clear, I was just referring to the even part of the expression. There can be an extra cos(x) left.

Comment: Technically, you can rewrite `cos(x)**3` as `(cos(x)**2)**(3 / 2)`, then `TR7` is able to apply its simplification. But the resulting expression would be different than the original: `cos(x)**3` varies between `[-1, 1]`, whereas the new expression varies from `[0, 1]`. They are not equivalent, which means your transformation rule doesn't hold.

Comment: Thanks, However I might need to correct my wording in the question because I never meant to do as you suggest. I would work out `cos(x)**3` as `cos(x)**2*cos(x)` and then apply the double-angle to `cos(x)**2` and subsequentely the addition/subtraction of angles to `cos(2*x)*cos(x)` (neglecting coefficients and the +1 term here).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function `rTR7` to recursively handle `cos(x)**(2*n)` and `cos(x)**(2*n + 1)` that rewrites the even exponent case as `expand(TR7(cos(x)**2)**n)` and the odd as `expand(cos(x)*rTR7(cos(x)**(2*n)))`:

```py
def rTR7(eq):
 # even powers
 was = None
 while was != eq:
  was = eq
  eq = eq.replace(lambda x: x.is_Pow and (x.base.func==cos) and x.exp%2==0,
  lambda x: expand(TR7(x.base**2)**(x.exp//2)))
 # odd powers
 was = None
 while was != eq:
  was = eq
  eq = eq.replace(lambda x: x.is_Pow and (x.base.func==cos) and x.exp%2,
  lambda x: expand(x.base*rTR7(x.base**(x.exp-1))))
 return eq

>>> rTR7(cos(x)**8)
cos(2*x)*cos(4*x)/8 + 3*cos(2*x)/8 + 7*cos(4*x)/32 + cos(8*x)/128 + 35/128
>>> rTR7(cos(x)**5)
cos(x)*cos(2*x)/2 + cos(x)*cos(4*x)/8 + 3*cos(x)/8
```

Comment: Thank you for the example using recursion - I think I can study that and apply the idea to other cases too, so that's very useful.
As far as the current implementation goes, my end goal is to have sums of `cos(n*x)` terms only, so there is some change to implement to expand `cos(2*x)*cos(4*x)` in the first application of `rTR7`, or `cos(x)*cos(2*x)` in the second one.